# Django Form is Not saving to Database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have searched the site for a solution, many related questions, but no direct response given. I have 3 apps on my projects, and 2 worked pretty well, except for this app, which is not writing to the database.

Yes, the other 2 apps write to the postgres database, and I can view the table, but this return empty rows, and I don't see any problem. I hope someone can help me, see below my Model, Form and View.py.

MY View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import EngForm

def EngineerList(request):
    return render(request, "Engineers/elist.html")


def EngineerForm(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
         form = EngForm()
         return render(request, "Engineers/eform.html", {'form':form})
    else:
         form = EngForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
         return redirect('/engineer/') #pointing to urls.py paths
```

My Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Engineers

class EngForm(forms.ModelForm):

      class Meta:
          model = Engineers
          fields = '__all__'
          labels = {
             'workarea' : 'Zone',
             'face' : 'Picture',
    
            }

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(EngForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.fields['position'].empty_label='Select'
          self.fields['workarea'].empty_label='Select'
          self.fields['face'].required = False
```

My Model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Engineers(models.Model):
   position = (
       ('NOC', 'NOC'),
       ('Supervisor', 'Supervisor'), 
       ('Site Manager','Site Manager'), 
       ('Site Engineer', 'Site Engineer'),
      )

   region = (
       ('SS','South-South'),('SW','SW'),('SE','SE'), 
       ('NE','NE'),('NW','NW'),('NC','NC'),
       )

   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   phone = models.IntegerField()
   position = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=position)
   workarea = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=region)
   face = models.ImageField(upload_to='', height_field=15, width_field=9)
```

My HTML

```
{% extends "Dashboard/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{form.face|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    <p>
    <hr>
    <p>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.firstname|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.lastname|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.username|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.position|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.phone|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{form.workarea|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
        {{form.email|as_crispy_field}}
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <hr>   
  <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
 {% endblock content %}
```

My problem is, the database table is returning empty row.

Comment: Your view is performing a redirect even if form will not validate. That means you will not know about any validation errors if they occur. My recommendation is to change your view to be more inline with an example from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#the-view) and see if your form validates properly.

Comment: Also, the `face` field in your model needs to have `blank=True` if it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Applied @GwynBleidD suggest, I reviewed the doc, and then rearranged the code as such.

```
def EngineerForm(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EngForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/engineer/') #pointing to urls.py paths
else:
    form = EngForm()
return render(request, "Engineers/eform.html", {'form':form})
```